# My code doesn't work online

Tags: php, ajax

```
<?php
include('changeLang.php'); 
$default_language = 'sr';
if(isset($_COOKIE['lang'])) {
    $lang = $_COOKIE['lang'];
} 
else {
    $lang = $default_language;
} 
if($lang == 'en') { 
    include('language_en.php');
} 
else {
    include('language_sr.php');
}
?>
```

I added a new URL path and I do not eject any error, Of course it's all in the same folder and there is no subfolders to immediately exclude the possibility. I think about mistake

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
function changeLanguage (lang) {

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://www.example.com/changeLang.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data:{ lang:lang },
        beforeSend: function(){

        },
        complete: function(){

        },
        success: function(data) {             
            console.log(data);
            if(data == 'ok'){
                location.reload();
            }
            //var response = JSON.parse(data);
        },
        error: function(data, textStatus, errorThrown){
            console.log("error"+' '+JSON.stringify(data) + textStatus  + errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

// in code

My mistke was in href, because i put href="" , the page was reloading at first and onclick functions never been used, so i have to put javascript:void(0) and in css curosr:pointer for div #flag....

Comment: Define *does not work*. What error are you getting ? What have you debug so far ?

Comment: **Eww**. Nobody is going to help you if you don't even try to help yourself. I'll give you a hint - narrow down your code to what isn't working and supply the errors (*if applicable*) to be helped further.

Comment: It would help if you fixed the indenting on the code so it didn't jump in and out of code formatting

Answer (score 1):

You are requesting `changeLang.php`, which won't be the name of the file online. You'll need the full [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator). The same applies to the image files.

For example, in the ajax section of the script, you have

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'changeLang.php',
```

Instead of requesting `changeLang.php`, add in the full file name, like `http://www.example.com/site/changeLang.php`. This specifies which server you're expecting to serve the file, and where you know it to be.

Locally, there is almost always only one server, and often a much simpler directory structure, cutting down on these mistakes. As soon as you put it online, the mistakes show up as errors. Remember also that error reporting settings for a live site will typically be much harsher than those in a development environment. You might want to check out your [php.ini](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php) file, both locally and online. You can [tune it](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) temporarily to show you all the fine details. It might help you figure out the problem.

Comment: **Uhhhhhh** `-->` It will work if they are in the same directory.

Comment: Absolutely right, but this has fixed problems on my side more times than I can count. Useful suggestion then

Comment: That's exactly right :-) Maybe update your answer with an example & better explanation to give OP an understanding!

Comment: +1 That's a better answer!

Comment: I added a new URL path and I do not eject any error, Of course it's all in the same folder and there is no subfolders to immediately exclude the possibility. I think about mistake